# WPF How to get hidden text range of trimmed text (with TextTrimming enabled)

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, texttrimming

How to get the trimmed text of the TextBlock when TextTrimming is set to "WordEllipsis" or "CharacterEllipsis" ?

For example, this code:

```
<TextBlock Name="text1" FontSize="12" Width="94" Text="THIS IS A LONG TEXT" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
```

displays: `THIS IS A...`

How to get the trimmed text: `LONG TEXT` or the index where the string is trimmed: `10`

Comment: The value of the Text property does not change. Only the text presentation by the TextBlock changes in that it replaces the clipping rendered text with the ellipsis.

Comment: I know the Text value does not change. Maybe there are workaround to get the trimmed text?

Comment: Then I misunderstood you. You have to measure the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually measure the text (with all the font styling applied).

A general solution that also works with `TextTrimming` set to `TextTrimming.WordEllipsis` would have to iteratively find the last character position.
Because there is nor related API we must do it the hard way and iteratively test until we don't get an exception anymore. There is no other way (the requirement to known the exact text portion that clips the available text area is usually not sensible).

However, when `TextTrimming` is set to `TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis` there won't be any exceptions thrown. This is because character based trimming produces a predictable result opposed to word trimming where the length of the words is random (because the words are not known). This means the `TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis` based case is more performance friendly.

Additionally, finding the multiple hidden text ranges of a multi-line `TextBlock` is a more complex scenario that is not addressed by the proposed solution.

The final solution that supports `TextTrimming.WordEllipsis` and `TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis` could look as follows:

```cs
public string GetHiddenRangeOfTrimmedText(TextBlock textBlock)
{
  var typeFace = new Typeface(textBlock.FontFamily, textBlock.FontStyle, textBlock.FontWeight, textBlock.FontStretch);
  var numberSubstitution = new NumberSubstitution(NumberSubstitution.GetCultureSource(textBlock), CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, NumberSubstitution.GetSubstitution(textBlock));

  // Define ellipsis using four ellipsis characters (instead of three).
  // This is because ellipsis is rendered using three visible and one hidden ellipsis characters.
  var formattedEllipsisText = new FormattedText(
    "....",
    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,
    textBlock.FlowDirection,
    typeFace,
    textBlock.FontSize,
    textBlock.Foreground,
    numberSubstitution,
    VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(textBlock).PixelsPerDip);
  double clippingOffset = textBlock.ActualWidth - formattedEllipsisText.Width - textBlock.Padding.Right;
  var clippingPosition = new Point(clippingOffset, 0);

  TextPointer clippingPositionTextPointer = null;
  do
  {
    try
    {
      clippingPositionTextPointer = textBlock.GetPositionFromPoint(clippingPosition, true);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
      if (clippingPosition.X == 0)
      {
        return string.Empty;
      }

      clippingPosition.Offset(-1, 0);
    }

    if (clippingPositionTextPointer is not null)
    {
      break;
    }
  } while (clippingPosition.X >= 0);

  var clippedTextRange = new TextRange(clippingPositionTextPointer, textBlock.ContentEnd);
  string clippedText = clippedTextRange.Text;
      
  return clippedText;
}

public int GetIndexOfHiddenRangeOfTrimmedText(TextBlock textBlock)
{
  string hiddenTextRange = GetHiddenRangeOfTrimmedText(textBlock);
  int indexOfHiddenTextRange = textBlock.Text.IndexOf(hiddenTextRange, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  return indexOfHidenTextRange;
}
```